# Union-set intersection-set for a binary-tree implementation of sets

Tags: tree, lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html):

> **Exercise 2.65**
>
> Use the results of
>   exercises 2.63 and  2.64 to give (n)
>   implementations of union-set and
>   intersection-set for sets implemented
>   as (balanced) binary trees.41

I wrote the following answer:

```
(define (union-set a b)
  (define (rec set1 set2)
    (cond ((null? set1) set2)
          ((null? set2) set1)
          ((= (car set1) (car set2)) (cons (car set1) (union-set (cdr set1) (cdr set2))))
          ((> (car set1) (car set2)) (cons (car set1) (union-set (cdr set1) set2)))
          (else (cons (car set2) (rec set1 (cdr set2))))))
  (let ((ls-result (rec (tree->list a) (tree->list b))))
    (partial-tree ls-result (length ls-result))))

(define (intersection-set a b)
  (define (rec set1 set2)
    (cond ((or (null? set1) (null? set2)) '())
          ((= (car set1) (car set2)) (cons (car set1) (rec (cdr set1) (cdr set2))))
          ((> (car set1) (car set2)) (rec set1 (cdr set2)))
          ((> (car set2) (car set1)) (rec (cdr set1) set2))))
  (let ((ls-result (rec (tree->list a) (tree->list b))))
    (partial-tree ls-result (length ls-result))))
```

Is this answer ok?  Could it be better?